# java binary text input

Tags: java, binary, format, jformattedtextfield

I am trying to make a Java program that translates text to binary and vice versa. However, I am struggling with the binary to text part. I figured out that you can add date and phone number formats using a JFormattedTextField. But I'm trying to make a more complicated format where the user can only type the numbers 1 and 0, and it adds a (not-selectable) dash between bytes.

(10011100-01001101 and you can copy it without copying the dash: you would copy 1001110001001101 to your clipboard instead)

I have no idea how to get the desired result. Can someone please explain how to make a format that only enables ones and zeros?

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find help in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Comment: I'm now using a MaskFormatter. Do they loop?

Comment: I'm also trying to get the user to be able to input binary text that extends as long as they want it to. I don't want the text to stop being added after the first byte. I'm currently using the code below:

MaskFormatter form=new MaskFormatter();
        try{
            form.setMask("########-");
        }catch(Exception e){}
        form.setValidCharacters("01");
        form.setPlaceholderCharacter('X');
        binary=new JFormattedTextField(form);

Comment: What I'm now trying to do is make the mask take 100101011111010101010111 and return 10010101-11110101-01010111 and be able to do that with any number of bytes.

Comment: I'm not an expert, sorry. I just searched and found that tutorial and thought it could help you.

Comment: Thanks! It really did help a lot, though. I now have a much better grasp of what jformattedtextfields are for.